# Empty values in if clauses

Tags: javascript

Here's a sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction();">Click!</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
var text = "";
if (text)
  {
  alert(text);
  }
else
  {
  alert("There's no text!");
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I wonder is there's a difference between *if (text)* and *if (text != "")*?

Thanks in advance!

Mike

Answer (score 2):

`if(text)` will evaluate to false if `text` is a null value, undefined value, 0, an empty string, or false. This is because the `if` statement is checking to see if `text` is a falsy value (e.g. null, undefined, 0, an empty string, or false).

`if(text != "")` checks to see if `text` does not equal an empty string. This means that the if statement will evaluate to true if `text` is a falsy value other than an empty string.

Comment: also the empty string is "falsy" too

Comment: If the `text` is `0`,or `"0"`?

Comment: Either or, Engineer, because `!=` does type casting.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Are you sure that `if(0){ alert('something');  }`, will execute the `alert`?

Comment: if `text` is `null` or `undefined`, `text != ""` will evalute to `true`. It will evaluate to `false` if `text` is `0`. You should explain the rules rather than listing some examples anyway

Comment: That's true as well--editing some more. I've actually never thought through this, because I always use `if(text)` or some equivalent.